# Result of initializer unused

Tags: json, swift, string, url, swift3

I was just wondering why I get this error. I have struct as 'Model' and initialize it from the `extract_data` function, which is called in `viewDidLoad()`, but when I set a breakpoint in the struct I can see that everything was initialised properly and whats strange to is if i take my label and set it to my `Struct.base String`, it doesn't work somehow...I'm a beginner so an explanation would really be appreciated:)

Here is my `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    get_data("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=CHF")

    testLabel.text = TestStruct().base
    //ANOTHER ERROR HERE (MISSING ARGUMENT FOR PARAMETER "base" IN CALL)
}

@IBOutlet var testLabel: UILabel!

var test:[TestStruct] = [TestStruct]()

func get_data(_ link:String){

    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let sessioin = URLSession.shared

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let testtask = sessioin.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        self.extract_data(data)
    })

    testtask.resume()
}

func extract_data(_ data:Data?){
    let json:Any?

    if(data==nil){
        return
    }

    do {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

        //The whole JSON
        let data_dictonary = json as? [String: Any]

        //Just the "base"
        let data_base = data_dictonary?["base"] as! String
        print(data_base)

        //Just the "date"
        let data_date = data_dictonary?["date"] as! String
        print(data_date)

        //All the exchange rates
        let data_rates = data_dictonary?["rates"] as! [String: Double]
        print(data_rates)

        TestStruct.init(base: data_base, date: data_date, rates: data_rates)
        //ERROR IS HERE

    }catch {
        return
    }
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var base: String
    var date: String
    var rates: [String: Double]

    init(base: String, date: String, rates: [String:Double]) {
        self.base = base
        self.date = date
        self.rates = rates
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you should learn standard naming conventions. Names should use camelCase - no underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for calling the initializer is incorrect. Change:

```
TestStruct.init(base: data_base, date: data_date, rates: data_rates)
```

to:

```
let someVar = TestStruct(base: data_base, date: data_date, rates: data_rates)
```

And the error with:

```
testLabel.text = TestStruct().base
```

is that you are trying to access the `base` property on a newly created `TestStruct` instance but you have no `init` on your `TestStruct` with no parameters.

You need to create `TestStruct` by passing all of the required arguments but that seems pointless since all you want is its `base` and you need the `base` to create the instance to begin with.

Comment: Hey thanks that worked :)...quick question do you know why I cant get my label working?

Comment: You never make use of the `TestStruct` instance you create in `extract_data`. I suggest adding a property to your view controller class that you can use to store the struct instance. Then reference the `base` attribute  of the property in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: That's not the right syntax. You need `var test: TestStruct?`.

Comment: In `extract_data`, instead of `let someVar = TestStruct...` you do `test = TestStruct...`. And you use `testLabel.text = test?.base` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Ok I did that set a breakpoint in Viewdidload to check and the its still nil, but why...

Comment: Use your debugger and step through all of your view controller code. Does it get to the point where it assigns a value to your new `test` property?

Comment: I even set a break point when I passed`test = TestStruct...` and printed it to the console the data is strored but it somehow disapears in ViewDidLoad. do you maybe think thats because the `testLabel.text = rates.base` is excecuted bevor the get_data function?